# How to load a component in index.js before AppRegistry.registerComponent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My React Native 0.70.x uses MS module react-native-code-push 7.x. The app structure is :

```
root 
 index.js
    App0.js. //<<==here is a privacy page which will shut down app if users choose reject policy
      App.js //<==here is the entry to the app
       ... //more pages
```

The `index.js` code throws error of `Invariant Violation: "[object Object]" has not been registered.This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
  `.

Here is index.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import App0 from './App0';

export default <App0 />;
```

Here is App0.js:

```
import React, { Component, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import Bye from "./src/components/app/Bye";
import App from './App';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';
import helper from "./src/lib/helper";
import {
    heightPercentageToDP as hp,
    widthPercentageToDP as wp,
   } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

//const Stack = createStackNavigator();
console.log("App is ", App);

export default function App0() {
    const [hasToken, setHasToken] = useState(false);
    const [hasYes, setHasYes] = useState(false);
    const [hasBye, setHasBye] = useState(false)

    const userYes = () => {
      setHasYes(true);
      AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
};

    const PrivacyPolicy = () => {
        console.log("In PrivacyPolicy");
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:60}}>
                <WebView
                style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20, width:wp("80%"), height:hp("75%"), fontSize:wp("2.5%")}}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{ uri: `https://emclab.github.io` }} 
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                />
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{userYes()}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:wp("3.5%"), color:"blue"}}>ACCEPT</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>      </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{setHasBye(true)}} >
                        <Text style={{fontSize:wp("3.5%"), color:"blue"}}>REJECT</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const asynctask = async () => {
            console.log("in asynctask");
            try {
                //let my_id = await helper.secureGet("myID"); //viewer_id      
                let _result = await helper.getJwtToken(); //JWT token and secret
                if (!_result) {
                    setHasToken(false);
                } else {
                    setHasToken(true);
                };
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error in App0.js : ", err);
                setHasToken(false);
            };
            
        };
    
        asynctask();

    }, []);
    //!userAcceptTC.current && !hasToken &&

    //console.log("hasYes : ", hasToken);
    return (<>
            {(hasYes || hasToken) && <App />}
            {!hasToken && !hasYes && !hasBye && <PrivacyPolicy />}
            {hasBye && <Bye />}
            </>); 
};
```

Also tried to return  in a component and export it (the error is the same). How to register a component in index.js and execute it before `AddRegistry.RegisterComponent`?